# Should I create a booleanfield index in a multi column indexing?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, indexing

For example, I want to retrieve next/previous post by `publish_date` and `published=True`. Should I create an index of `publish_date, published` or just `publish_date`?

Table is

```
id (int) 
title (char) 
description (text) 
publish_date (datetime) 
published (bool)
```

Query is:

```
select * 
from table 
where publish_date > current_post.publish_date 
  and published = True
order by publish_date
limit 1
```

Which indexing will be better?

- Multi-column indexing on `(publish_time, published)`

or

- Single column indexing on just `(publish_time)`

Comment: If you do use a multicolumn index, you need a comma, not "and".  How often is published true?  If almost always, then there isn't much point.  If almost never, then you probably want a filtered index, not multicolumn.

Comment: 80 percent published=true

Comment: `publish_date>current_post.publish_date` -- Eh?  why are you mentioning `publish_date` twice; `current_post` is not mentioned.

Comment: i am using it with web application. just want to know which index will be better for such type of condition. @rickJames

Answer (score 0):

Let me first rewrite the query so it makes more sense:

```
select * from table 
    where publish_date >= '2020-01-01'
      and published = True
    ORDER BY publish_date
    LIMIT 1
```

This index would be optimal:

```
INDEX(published, publish_date)
```

with the columns in that order.  First come things tested with `=`, then at most one range.  Both columns will be used in the `WHERE`.  And, since that handles the entire `WHERE`, it will move on to the `ORDER BY`.  The `ORDER BY` matches the `WHERE` well enough that it will help with it, thereby avoiding any sort.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

See also `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

The cardinality of each column does not matter when it is part of a composite index.